# I want to copy the text from <p> tag which is stored in database by a click on a button named "Copy"

Tags: c#, .net, repeater

I'm using a repeater, which has a class "main", in the main class, it consist Header `<h1>` and `<p>`.

`<P>` have some text. They are stored in database.

Now I want to put a button named "Copy" below. When user clicks on the button, the text inside the `<p>` tag should be copied.

Please tell me how can I do this..?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="one">
            <h1><asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Categories") %>'/></h1>
            <p><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Post") %>'/></P>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy" />
            <div id="by">  Posted By: <asp:Label ID="lblby" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("posted_by") %>' ForeColor="#000066"/> </div><!-- End of one-->
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: First thing would be to try, cause ven if you wish it very hard, it's not going to code itself up, and SO crew most probably won't code it for you...

Comment: Also you don't say where you want to copy it to! Client/server side and what you want to do with it after that. A hit would be search for 'repeater command' and read, then try, then read a bit more! All the answers to this problem are in the msdn docs

Comment: text shud be copied to client side, this is a site of Quotes, so user can copy d quotes by simply clicking d button and thn he/she can past it to anywhere in d his/her PC.